# Explain the result I got from WEKA

Tags: output, weka

I'm a newbie on using WEKA so could you explain me the following results I got from trying to train data using MultilayerPerceptron (Neural Network):

Also could you atleast give me some links that could help me understand this?

```
=== Run information ===

Scheme:weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -L 0.3 -M 0.2 -N 500 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H a -G -R
Relation:     Dengue
Instances:    520
Attributes:   12
              MinTemp
              MaxTemp
              MeanTemp
              RelativeHumidity
              Rainfall
              Wind
              LandArea
              IncomeClass
              WasteGenerated
              PopulationDensity
              HouseNumber
              Dengue
Test mode:evaluate on training data

=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

Linear Node 0
    Inputs    Weights
    Threshold    1.045699824540429
    Node 1    -0.7885241220010747
    Node 2    -0.5679021300029351
    Node 3    -0.6990681220652758
    Node 4    -1.7036399417988182
    Node 5    -1.7986596505677839
    Node 6    -1.0031026344357001
Sigmoid Node 1
    Inputs    Weights
    Threshold    -2.7846715622473632
    Attrib MinTemp    -0.3756262925227143
    Attrib MaxTemp    -1.0113362508935868
    Attrib MeanTemp    -0.6867107452689675
    Attrib RelativeHumidity    -1.357278537485863
    Attrib Rainfall    0.9346189251054217
    Attrib Wind    -2.4697988150023895
    Attrib LandArea    -0.04802972345084459
    Attrib IncomeClass    -0.0023757695994812353
    Attrib WasteGenerated    -0.5219516258114455
    Attrib PopulationDensity    0.6275856253232837
    Attrib HouseNumber    0.4794517421072107
Sigmoid Node 2
    Inputs    Weights
    Threshold    -2.238113558499396
    Attrib MinTemp    0.6634817443452294
    Attrib MaxTemp    0.04177526569735764
    Attrib MeanTemp    0.4213111516398967
    Attrib RelativeHumidity    0.9477161615423007
    Attrib Rainfall    -0.06941110528380763
    Attrib Wind    0.1398767209217198
    Attrib LandArea    0.011908782901326666
    Attrib IncomeClass    -0.03177518077905532
    Attrib WasteGenerated    -2.111275394512881
    Attrib PopulationDensity    -0.002225384228836655
    Attrib HouseNumber    -0.18689477740073276
Sigmoid Node 3
    Inputs    Weights
    Threshold    -1.5469990007413668
    Attrib MinTemp    -0.538188914566223
    Attrib MaxTemp    0.2452404814154855
    Attrib MeanTemp    -0.07155897171503904
    Attrib RelativeHumidity    -0.6490463479419373
    Attrib Rainfall    1.2010399306686497
    Attrib Wind    0.7275195821368675
    Attrib LandArea    -0.033472141554108756
    Attrib IncomeClass    0.021303339082304765
    Attrib WasteGenerated    -0.12403826628027773
    Attrib PopulationDensity    -0.2663352902864381
    Attrib HouseNumber    0.5153046727550502
Sigmoid Node 4
    Inputs    Weights
    Threshold    -1.3273158445760431
    Attrib MinTemp    -0.511476470658412
    Attrib MaxTemp    -1.4472764735477759
    Attrib MeanTemp    -0.992550007766579
    Attrib RelativeHumidity    -0.4889201348001783
    Attrib Rainfall    4.777705232733897
    Attrib Wind    1.0057960261924193
    Attrib LandArea    0.01594686951090471
    Attrib IncomeClass    -0.012053049723794618
    Attrib WasteGenerated    -0.29397677127551647
    Attrib PopulationDensity    0.8760275665744505
    Attrib HouseNumber    0.26513119051179107
Sigmoid Node 5
    Inputs    Weights
    Threshold    0.9085281334048771
    Attrib MinTemp    -2.3264253136843633
    Attrib MaxTemp    4.342385678707546
    Attrib MeanTemp    1.26274142914379
    Attrib RelativeHumidity    0.3589371377240767
    Attrib Rainfall    -6.060544069949767
    Attrib Wind    -1.7001357028288409
    Attrib LandArea    -0.04696606932834255
    Attrib IncomeClass    -0.02765457448569584
    Attrib WasteGenerated    -4.685692052378084
    Attrib PopulationDensity    0.7497806979087069
    Attrib HouseNumber    -1.817884131764966
Sigmoid Node 6
    Inputs    Weights
    Threshold    -2.343332128576834
    Attrib MinTemp    -1.7808827758329944
    Attrib MaxTemp    2.3738961064086217
    Attrib MeanTemp    0.6053466030736496
    Attrib RelativeHumidity    0.4178221348007889
    Attrib Rainfall    0.2646387686505043
    Attrib Wind    0.6941590574632328
    Attrib LandArea    0.022879267506905346
    Attrib IncomeClass    -0.030599400189594162
    Attrib WasteGenerated    0.2341906598765536
    Attrib PopulationDensity    -0.054518515830522876
    Attrib HouseNumber    -0.6802930287343757
Class 
    Input
    Node 0


Time taken to build model: 17.83 seconds

=== Evaluation on training set ===
=== Summary ===

Correlation coefficient                  0.7747
Mean absolute error                      1.477 
Root mean squared error                  1.9605
Relative absolute error                110.9364 %
Root relative squared error             86.4544 %
Total Number of Instances              518     
Ignored Class Unknown Instances                  2
```

Answer (score 2):

You ran the Multilayer Perceptron (MLP) algorithm against the data. MLP uses backpropagation to classify instances. I'm going to assume you are familiar with basic statistics, the concept of backpropagation, and artificial neural networks since you chose this particular algorithm to train your model. If this is not the case, you have put the cart before the horse and need to learn the math before using this model. [Here is a training presentation that may help you if this is the case.](http://www3.dsi.uminho.pt/pcortez/mg.pdf)

After it says 'run information,' it shows the command you ran and all the parameters which you set (explained in [Weka documentation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/MultilayerPerceptron.html) - you chose them or at least went with defaults). After this it shows you are using the Dengue file (presumably data related to the fever and demographics of those infected, but since you chose this data I would presume you have a basic understanding of how it was collected and what the data is). Instances is the number of samples in the data file, and attributes is the number of columns.

The sigmoid nodes are the nodes used in backpropogation and the associated data. This is the network itself (its weights and attributes). The nodes in the hidden layer of this network are all sigmoid but the output nodes are linear units (eg. linear node 0 is your output unit and sigmoid nodes 1-6 are your six hidden units. All the values given are your interconnection weights. You can use them to manually calculate your results (which is done for you below the network).

As I just said, the bottom part is the final results calculated from the network. This part is all basic statistics so I won't elaborate any further.

Comment: Can the weights be related in any way to the class to be predicted?